# Empty Template with Edit a copy option

Tags: uwp, custom-controls, uwp-xaml

While editing the Template with Edit Copy option for UWP custom controls in VisualStudio empty Template created.

Please advise me to resolve it.

Regards,

Priyanga B

Answer (score 0):

If you created the custom control by the Visual Studio `Tempalted Control` template, it should work.

[image]

Ensure you are right click the correct control. Ensure the custom control do have default template. By default, check the `Themes` folder, and to see if there is a style target the custom control in `Generic.xaml` that contains `template` property.

More details please reference [Use tools to work with themes easily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates#use-tools-to-work-with-themes-easily).If you still have issues, please provide a minimal reproduced project.

Comment: Please provide solution for below query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562478/static-resource-defined-in-themedictionaries-not-fetched-while-edit-a-copy-of-th)